Compute fractional sub-binary contributions to a property of a point in N dimensions
For context, I will explain this problem from my POV, as I continued to work through it. TL;DR at the bottom.

Given the reference triangle $\triangle P_1P_2P_3$, draw the cevians through interior point M until they reach the opposite sides of the triangle at feet $Q_1$, $Q_2$, $Q_3$. Draw triangle $\triangle Q_1Q_2Q_3$ between these points. The points of intersection between cevians $\overline{P_1Q_1}$, $\overline{P_2Q_2}$, $\overline{P_3Q_3}$ and cevian-connectors $\overline{Q_2Q_3}$, $\overline{Q_1Q_3}$, $\overline{Q_1Q_2}$, are points $R_1$, $R_2$, $R_3$, respectively.

I want to find the length ratios $\phi_{\small{23}} = \frac{MR_1}{Q_1R_1}$, $\phi_{\small{13}} = \frac{MR_2}{Q_2R_2}$, $\phi_{\small{12}} = \frac{MR_3}{Q_3R_3}$, where it is known that $\phi_{\small{12}} + \phi_{\small{13}} + \phi_{\small{23}} = 1$.
For context, this problem arises from the idea of a ternary diagram in thermodynamics. The corners represent the three pure-component points of a mixture of three chemicals, and point $M$ represents the mixture composition in barycentric coordinates, where each coordinate represents the fraction $x_i$ of component $i$ in the mixture such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{3}x_i = 1$. Instead of reading a composition as a linear combination of pure component mole fractions, I am wanting to determine the "fraction" of each sub-binary mixture (to capture binary interaction effects between species). $\phi_{\small{12}}$, $\phi_{\small{13}}$, $\phi_{\small{23}}$ are those sub-binary fractions; I am basically using the lever rule on a transformed ternary diagram formed by $\triangle Q_1Q_2Q_3$, whose corners are the "pure" sub-binaries. The idea, then, is to use these sub-binary fractions to compute a sort of binary-averaged property (as opposed to the simpler pure-component weighted average) for the overall mixture $M$. You can consider the cevian line from one pure corner through the mixture point $M$ to the opposite binary to represent a mass-balance between the pure corner and the binary edge. Indeed, all straight line segments in this space represent linear combinations between two points.
Now back to the problem, I'll skip a lot of my trial and error, but instead of calculating the ratios of distances from the intersections of many lines that I initially envisioned (which are rather expensive calculations for my purposes), I found a far simpler way to determine the ratios I want:
If point $M$ has barycentric coordinates $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and points $P_1$, $P_2$, $P_3$ have coordinates $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, $(0,0,1)$, I can compute the "binary fraction" I want as $\phi_{ij} = \frac{1}{2}(x_i + x_j)$. Two useful properties I want these $\phi_{ij}$s to have, if they are correctly derived, are the following:

$\sum\limits_{i,j}\phi_{ij} = 1$ $\forall \ {N_c \choose 2}$ combinations of $i,j$
$\sum\limits_{j,j\neq i}^{N_c}\phi_{ij}\left( \frac{x_i}{x_i + x_j} \right) = x_i$

Property #1 says "the sum of all binary contributions must add up to 1" (remain barycentric). Property #2 says "the sum of the relative amounts of component $i$ in all sub-binaries containing component $i$ should equal the overall amount of component $i$ in the mixture $M$" (conservation of mass). These conditions will be important later.
I should also mention the implicit Property #0 for barycentric coordinates:

$\sum\limits_{i}^{N_c}x_i = 1$

In this sense, you can view the inner triangle $\triangle Q_1Q_2Q_3$ as an affine transformation of $\triangle P_1P_2P_3$, though I haven't been able to make use of this fact yet.

This is all well and good for a 3-barycentric-dimensional space like I have here, but I want this procedure to generalize to $N_c$ dimensions (where $N_c$ = "number of components"). Consider for a moment the 4-component (tetrahedral) space below:

I won't get into specifics for this case, but it's important to note that no matter the dimensionality, I want the projection of the mixture point onto the sub-binary mixtures/edges, not simply the $(N_c-1)$-dimensional feature (faces, in this case). This is mainly because that algorithm would have factorial runtime w.r.t. $N_c$, and I want the eventual procedure to be quite fast, with $N_c$ theoretically as high as 40 (though typically not >20)...
Note that there is a peculiarity in the 4-D case: if you draw a line (blue) from one sub-binary point (green) through the overall mixture point $M$ to the opposite site of the space, you land on another sub-binary mixture (specifically, the one with the other two components that were excluded from the first binary)! I struggled with this for a while, but I now believe this is just an artifact of 4-D (in 3-D, opposite of an edge is an orthogonal corner; in 5-D, opposite of an edge is an orthogonal face; in $N_c$-D, opposite of an edge is an orthogonal $(N_c-2)$-D feature).
Anyway, similarly to the 3-D case, I found for this 4-D case that I could replace the calculation of the ratios of distances with $\phi_{ij} = \frac{1}{N_c-1}(x_i+x_j)$. The factor of $\frac{1}{N_c-1}$ comes from substituting the previous expression into Property #1 from earlier; you end up with a sum of $N_c-1$ copies of each fraction $x_i$, so you must divide by that factor to return to a sum of 1.
I thought for a while that this problem was solved, until I tested it on various compositions. In the following image, the vertical axis is the property I am trying to average, and the horizontal plane contains the 3 barycentric dimensions of a ternary mixture:

All points represent mixtures for whose vertical coordinate is the sub-binary-average of the true binary properties (edges). You'll notice at all edges (but most prominently along the red edge) though that there are discontinuities between the edge points and the interior points. This is because, in my code, when a point lies on the edge, I simply compute a normal binary property, but when a point has three components present (3 non-zero barycentric coordinates) I use the sub-binary average method I have found. This led me to the unfortunate realization that, under the current scheme, if any component $i$ is not present ($x_i=0$), sub-binary fractions $\phi_{ij}$ that contain component $i$ will not equal zero! This fact is rather obvious when you consider my current working definition for the binary fraction.
From this, I have determined two additional required properties for a sensible definition of $\phi_{ij}$:

$\phi_{ij}=0$ if either $x_i=0$ or $x_j=0$, $\forall$ choices of $i,j$
For any mixture property $f_{\mathrm{mix}}$ which I want to estimate, $f_{\mathrm{mix}}(\mathbf{x})=\sum\limits_{i,j}\phi_{ij}f_{ij}(x_i,x_j)$, the function should be continuous and smooth everywhere

Property #3 says that "a sub-binary cannot contribute to the overall mixture if either of its two components is not present". Property #4's relevance to the most recent problem is "$f_{\mathrm{mix}}$ should be continuous along the binary edges and smooth in directions perpendicular to all binary edges".
So this brings me to the part where I ask for help, because I am way out of my depth with this type of geometry. Along this process, I have found many seemingly relevant concepts such as the Cayley-Menger determinant, affine maps, multilinear interpolations, and more, but I have yet to find a useful implementation of these ideas. I basically want the following in an ideal formulation of a "sub-binary fraction":

TL;DR:
In a barycentric space of dimension $N_c$, with vertices representing pure components in a mixture, I want to estimate the value of some function at a non-degenerate mixture point by performing a weighted average of the "sub-binary" points (overall mixture projected onto binary edges), with the mathematical expression for the sub-binary fraction satisfying the following conditions...

Properties #0, #1, #2, #3, #4 from above must hold
Must be relatively efficient to compute, preferably $\mathcal{O}({N_c}^2)$ (which I believe is the best case for ${N_c \choose 2}$ sub-binaries), and certainly not $\mathcal{O}(N_c!)$ (which is the complexity of a recursive, "+1 dimension at a time" approach)

I have wondered, though, if this is even possible. Particularly, the combination of Properties #1 and #3 imply to me that a functional definition of $\phi_{ij}$ will necessarily be rather complicated, as it needs to both capture linearity (Prop. #1) and run to zero if one component in the sub-binary runs to zero (Prop. #3), which seems to imply a geometric/multiplicative nature.
If anyone can come up with something clever here, I would be extremely grateful!
